# PictureBox hover over Parameter is not valid issue

Tags: c#, mouseevent, picturebox

I have 3 picture boxes which hold an image from a list string. There is a button which goes through each element in the list string, which in turn updates the 3 picture boxes the picture boxes that hold the 3 images are, picturebox3, 4 and 5. i have added a mouse event that triggers once the mouse is on the image to expand the image in another picturebox which is hidden until the mouse is on top of it. i created 3 extra pictureboxes which are pictureBox6, 7 and 8 to show the enlarged image which relate to picturebox3, 4 and 5. picturebox 6 is related to 3, picturebox 7 is related to 4 and 8 is related to 5.
I have tried to set the picturebox to null after the mouse is off the image however that hasn’t worked.
Below is the code for the image in picturebox 3, 4 and 5 to be updated as it goes through the list it also includes the event triggers.

download_file_names[] = the filename ".jpg"
matching_image_for_Processing[intIndex] = the folder which holds the file

Those variables above do change as i go through the list so i know that works

I have tried to set the picturebox to null after the mouse is off the image however that hasnt worked.

Below is the code for the image in picturebox 3, 4 and 5 to be updated as it goes through the list it also includes the event triggers.

```
if (download_file_names.ElementAtOrDefault(0) != null)
               {
                   pictureBox3.Image = new Bitmap(Environment.CurrentDirectory + "\\" + "temp_data" + "\\" + matching_image_for_Processing[intIndex] + "\\" + download_file_names[0]);
                   pictureBox3.MouseHover += new EventHandler((sender2, e2) => pictureBox3_Mouse(sender2, e2, download_file_names[0], matching_image_for_Processing[intIndex]));
                   pictureBox3.MouseLeave += new EventHandler(pictureBox3_MouseLeave);
               }
               else
               {
                   pictureBox3.Image = new Bitmap(Environment.CurrentDirectory + "\\" + "NoImage.bmp");

               }

               if (download_file_names.ElementAtOrDefault(1) != null)
               {
                   pictureBox4.Image = new Bitmap(Environment.CurrentDirectory + "\\" + "temp_data" + "\\" + matching_image_for_Processing[intIndex] + "\\" + download_file_names[1]);
                   pictureBox4.MouseHover += new EventHandler((sender2, e2) => pictureBox4_Mouse(sender2, e2, download_file_names[1], matching_image_for_Processing[intIndex]));
                   pictureBox4.MouseLeave += new EventHandler(pictureBox4_MouseLeave);
               }
               else
               {
                   pictureBox4.Image = new Bitmap(Environment.CurrentDirectory + "\\" + "NoImage.bmp");
               }

               if (download_file_names.ElementAtOrDefault(2) != null)
               {
                   pictureBox5.Image = new Bitmap(Environment.CurrentDirectory + "\\" + "temp_data" + "\\" + matching_image_for_Processing[intIndex] + "\\" + download_file_names[2]);
                   pictureBox5.MouseHover += new EventHandler((sender2, e2) => pictureBox5_Mouse(sender2, e2, download_file_names[2], matching_image_for_Processing[intIndex]));
                   pictureBox5.MouseLeave += new EventHandler(pictureBox5_MouseLeave);

               }
               else
               {
                   pictureBox5.Image = new Bitmap(Environment.CurrentDirectory + "\\" + "NoImage.bmp");
               }
```

below is the code for the other picturesboxes to display the larger image.

```
void pictureBox3_Mouse(object sender, EventArgs e, string catching, string catching2)
       {

           pictureBox6.Visible = true;
           pictureBox6.Image = new Bitmap(Environment.CurrentDirectory + "\\" + "temp_data" + "\\" + catching2 + "\\" + catching);
           Console.WriteLine("temp_data" + "\\" + catching2 + "\\" + catching);
           pictureBox6.Refresh();




       }

       void pictureBox3_MouseLeave(object sender, EventArgs e)
       {
           pictureBox6.Visible = false;
           pictureBox6.Image = null;
           pictureBox6.Refresh();

       }

       void pictureBox4_Mouse(object sender, EventArgs e, string catching_1, string catching2_1)
       {


                pictureBox7.Visible = true;
               pictureBox7.Image = new Bitmap(Environment.CurrentDirectory + "\\" + "temp_data" + "\\" + catching2_1 + "\\" + catching_1);
               pictureBox7.Refresh();


       }

       void pictureBox4_MouseLeave(object sender, EventArgs e)
       {
           pictureBox7.Visible = false;
           pictureBox7.Image = null;
           pictureBox7.Refresh();

       }

       void pictureBox5_Mouse(object sender, EventArgs e, string catching_2, string catching2_2)
       {


              pictureBox8.Visible = true;
               pictureBox8.Image = new Bitmap(Environment.CurrentDirectory + "\\" + "temp_data" + "\\" + catching2_2 + "\\" + catching_2);
               pictureBox8.Refresh();


       }

       void pictureBox5_MouseLeave(object sender, EventArgs e)
       {
           pictureBox8.Visible = false;
           pictureBox8.Image = null;
           pictureBox8.Refresh();

       }
```

I am hoping someone can help me solve this issue, as i go to the next element in the list and hover over the new image i keep getting the error Parameter is not valid. i believe the picturebox is holding the previous variable.

Comment: Did you really mean to setup all the mouse overs with `matching_image_for_Processing[intIndex]` ? would that not change for each of the images

Comment: Use **PictureBox.Image?.Dispose()** instead of _null_ it..